# How to mock Autofac.Multitenant.MultitenantContainer.ConfigureTenant

Tags: .net, nunit, moq, autofac, multi-tenant

I have a code that looks something like this:

```cs
private readonly ITenantProvdier _tenantProvider;

//ctor ...

public void ConfigureNewTenants( MultitenantContainer multiTenantContainer )
{
    var tenants = _tenantProvider.GetNewTenantsToAdd(); //gets tenants that are just added during the runtime.
    
    foreach( var tenant in tenants )
    {
        try
        {
            multiTenantContainer.ConfigureTenant( tenant.Id, someCustomAction);
        }
        catch( ArgumentNullException exception )
        {
            // log error and do smth
        }
        catch( InvalidOperationException exception )
        {
            // log error and do smth
        }
    }
}
```

My goal is to test the code behavior when `multiTenantContainer` throws `ArgumentNullException` or `InvalidOperationException`.

I am using NUnit and Moq.
And tried to do next:

```cs
var containerMock = new Mock<MultitenantContainer>();
containerMock
  .Setup(c => c.ConfigureTenant(It.IsAny<object>, It.IsAny<Action<ContainerBuilder>>)
  .Thows(someException);
```

But it didn't work because method `ConfigureTenant` has next signature: `public void ConfigureTenant(object tenantId, Action<ContainerBuilder> configuration)`. And non-virtual class methods cannot be mocked.

I have tried to create a derived class with a `virtual new` method. It didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

mate. In your example you will get such error:

```
Unsupported expression: c => c.ConfigureTenant(It.IsAny<object>(), It.IsAny<Action<ContainerBuilder>>())
Non-overridable members (here: MultitenantContainer.ConfigureTenant) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.
```

`Moq` said he could not mock non-virtual method.
*Do we have solution for this?* - Yes!

You need to extract the `interface` out of your method and mock it or mark the method as `virtual`. In your case it is better to choose `interface` option.
*Let's try!*

---

I tried to create example similar to your:

1. Wrap method in interface

```
    public interface IConfigureNewTenants
    {
        void ConfigureNewTenants(MultitenantContainer multiTenantContainer, 
            int id, 
            Action<ContainerBuilder> action);
    }
```

2. Create implementation for it

```
    public class NewTenats : IConfigureNewTenants
    {
        public void ConfigureNewTenants(MultitenantContainer multiTenantContainer, 
            int id, 
            Action<ContainerBuilder> action)
        {
            multiTenantContainer.ConfigureTenant(id, action);
        }
    }
```

3. Mock method

```
            // Arrnage
            configureNewTenantsMock
                .Setup(x => x.ConfigureNewTenants(multitenantContainer.Object, 
                    It.IsAny<int>(), 
                    It.IsAny<Action<ContainerBuilder>>()))
                .Throws<InvalidOperationException>();
```

4. And test it!

```
            // Act
            Action act = () => manager.ConfigureNewTenants(multitenantContainer.Object);

            // Assert
            act.Should().Throw<InvalidOperationException>()
                .And.Message
                .Should().Be("InvalidOperationExceptionMessage");
```

5. Run test
   [image: Test]

This is the main idea how to workaround the problem.
Full solution has more lines of code that is way I created [gist](https://gist.github.com/DarkSideMoon/72905ad9765fbf5efcf255e8c49a412a) for it.